# Trying to utilise CTE for an IF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count, common-table-expression

I'm using SQL as part of an automated process to run a recompile if a trigger is met.  I need to output either the number '0' or the number '2' for the automation software.  I've written the following query and it works, but I'm trying to develop my knowledge so couple of questions...

In the following, am I using a CTE or sub-query?  Also, could this simple query be improved?

```
USE ErrorLog
GO

DECLARE @Rslt AS INT

SET @Rslt = (
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM [ErrorLog].[dbo].[ErrorLog]
  WHERE system = 'BEMA' AND Message LIKE 'Timeout expired%'
  AND errDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))

IF 
    (@Rslt > '0')
    BEGIN
        SELECT 2
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0
    END
```

Comment: You are using `sub-query`. The common table expression has different syntax.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the result directly:

```
SELECT IIF(COUNT(*) > 0, 2, 0)
FROM [ErrorLog].[dbo].[ErrorLog]
WHERE system = 'BEMA' AND Message LIKE 'Timeout expired%'
    AND errDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

or assigned it directly:

```
DECLARE @Rslt AS INT

SELECT @Rslt = IIF(COUNT(*) > 0, 2, 0)
FROM [ErrorLog].[dbo].[ErrorLog]
WHERE system = 'BEMA' AND Message LIKE 'Timeout expired%'
    AND errDate > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

AS `IIF` is availabel from SQL Server 2012, you need to use `CASE WHEN` for previous versions.